# VS2012 compile .net 4?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012

I've been working on a huge project that I created from the ground up using VS2012 MVC 4.5. I published it on our server that only has .net 4.0 installed on it and i'm running into errors (understably).  Corp IT says it'll be a couple months before they approve and install 4.5 -
Is there a way VS2012 can compile the project as 4.0?  And if it is possible, do i lose functionality like, bundling/minification, etc.?

I'd hate to have to try to port all my code over to VS2010....

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply open up the project properties and change the "Target framework" on the "Application" tab to ".NET Framework 4".

Comment: what about the 2nd part of the question - will all the nuget bundling/minification stuff still work?

Comment: Yes, they should as these are not features of the runtime but of the Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the Target framework to just about any version that you would want, including .Net 4.0

[image]

Comment: What I find interesting is how they label "2.0", "3.0" but then "4"? Consistency...

Comment: That's the fault of the Marketing guys. These are the official names.

Answer (score 0):

You can set TargetFramework to 4.0 :)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's also possible to specify the toolset in msbuild when you build your project by using

msbuild yoursolution.sln /toolsversion:4.0

This way you won't have to change it in your project settings.

This link explains in more detail about toolsets
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383796.aspx

Comment: The tools version is entirely separate from the target framework version. The tools version can be higher, lower, or the same, without problems. (And it's remained at 4.0 for VS2012 / .NET 4.5.)